# Django: logout_then_login() fails when using regex alternative

Tags: django, authentication, url-routing

I have this urls on urls.py

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
    {'template_name':'login.html'}),

url(r'^(one|two)/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login',
    {'login_url':'/login/'})
```

I'm trying to send `login_url` to logout_then_login() using the context dict, but this gives:

```
TypeError at /one/logout/

logout_then_login() got multiple values for keyword argument 'login_url'
```

This error only happens when using the alternative `(one|two)`. Shouldn't I be able to use this alternative, instead of two different urls for the same view? Would it be recommended?

Edit: Real problem identified and question updated accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine; `logout_then_login` accepts a `login_url` parameter and has since at least Django 1.0. If there's an error, it's being caused somewhere else in your project. Posting the full traceback may help, but in general, you need to look for any other place in your code where `login_url` is being passed, perhaps in an override.

**UPDATE**

The parenthetical group there is captured and passed as an arg to the method. You need to use a non-capturing group, e.g.:

```
url(r'^(?:one|two)/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login',
{'login_url':'/login/'})
```

Comment: You're right. I updated the question with the real problem: a regex alternative